# Autodesk Infrastructure Map Server - WFS 1.1.0 GetFeature Request error

Tags: wfs, mapguide, getfeature, autodesk

This is a duplicate request posted on the [AutoDesk MapGuide Enterprise Discussion Group](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Autodesk-MapGuide-Enterprise/GetFeature-how-to-declare-wfs-ogc-gml-namespaces/m-p/3732732#M3339).

If I take a working request...

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0" maxFeatures="10"
xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
  <wfs:Query typeName="Water:WA_LARGE_VALVE" SRSNAME="EPSG:26910">
    <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <Intersects xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
        <PropertyName>Geometry</PropertyName>
        <Envelope srsName="EPSG:26910">
          <lowerCorner>491784.0 5456759.0</lowerCorner>
          <upperCorner>491809.0 5456805.0</upperCorner>
        </Envelope>
      </Intersects>
    </Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

And replace Envelope with Polygon it fails...

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0" maxFeatures="1"
xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
  <wfs:Query typeName="Water:WA_LARGE_VALVE" SRSNAME="EPSG:26910">
    <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <Intersects xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
        <PropertyName>Geometry</PropertyName>
        <Polygon srsName="EPSG:26910">
          <exterior>
            <LinearRing>
              <posList>489093.629 5456057.158 489092.66826402
              5456047.4034839 489089.822976626 5456038.02382838
              489085.202480615 5456029.37948835 489078.984339059
              5456021.80266094 489071.407511651 5456015.58451938
              489062.763171618 5456010.96402337 489053.383516101
              5456008.11873598 489043.629 5456007.158 489033.874483899
              5456008.11873598 489024.494828382 5456010.96402337
              489015.850488349 5456015.58451938 489008.273660941
              5456021.80266094 489002.055519385 5456029.37948835
              488997.435023374 5456038.02382838 488994.58973598 5456047.4034839
              488993.629 5456057.158 488994.58973598 5456066.9125161
              488997.435023374 5456076.29217162 489002.055519385
              5456084.93651165 489008.273660941 5456092.51333906
              489015.850488349 5456098.73148062 489024.494828382
              5456103.35197663 489033.874483899 5456106.19726402 489043.629
              5456107.158 489053.383516101 5456106.19726402 489062.763171618
              5456103.35197663 489071.407511651 5456098.73148062
              489078.984339059 5456092.51333906 489085.202480615
              5456084.93651165 489089.822976626 5456076.29217162
              489092.66826402 5456066.9125161 489093.629
              5456057.158</posList>
            </LinearRing>
          </exterior>
        </Polygon>
        </Intersects>
    </Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

I receive is this error:

```
An exception occurred in FDO component.
    String does not represent a valid filter
```

Is there something wrong with this request or maybe both requests?

Comment: I found http://cite.opengeospatial.org/test_engine/wfs/1.1.0/ with links to test scripts.  Inside WFS_1.1.0_ETS\scripts\wfs-1.1.0-r3\ctl\all.xml I found many examples of GetFeature requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a space after the "  posList   " and it will work.  So this will fail:

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0" maxFeatures="1"
xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
  <wfs:Query typeName="Water:WA_LARGE_VALVE" SRSNAME="EPSG:26910">
    <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <Intersects>
        <PropertyName>Geometry</PropertyName>
        <Polygon srsName="EPSG:26910" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
          <exterior>
            <LinearRing>
              <posList>489093.629 5456057.158 489092.66826402
                5456047.4034839 489089.822976626 5456038.02382838
                489085.202480615 5456029.37948835 489078.984339059
                5456021.80266094 489071.407511651 5456015.58451938
                489062.763171618 5456010.96402337 489053.383516101
                5456008.11873598 489043.629 5456007.158 489033.874483899
                5456008.11873598 489024.494828382 5456010.96402337
                489015.850488349 5456015.58451938 489008.273660941
                5456021.80266094 489002.055519385 5456029.37948835
                488997.435023374 5456038.02382838 488994.58973598 5456047.4034839
                488993.629 5456057.158 488994.58973598 5456066.9125161
                488997.435023374 5456076.29217162 489002.055519385
                5456084.93651165 489008.273660941 5456092.51333906
                489015.850488349 5456098.73148062 489024.494828382
                5456103.35197663 489033.874483899 5456106.19726402 489043.629
                5456107.158 489053.383516101 5456106.19726402 489062.763171618
                5456103.35197663 489071.407511651 5456098.73148062
                489078.984339059 5456092.51333906 489085.202480615
                5456084.93651165 489089.822976626 5456076.29217162
                489092.66826402 5456066.9125161 489093.629
                5456057.158
              </posList>
            </LinearRing>
          </exterior>
        </Polygon>
      </Intersects>
    </Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

And this will succeed:

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0" maxFeatures="1"
xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
  <wfs:Query typeName="Water:WA_LARGE_VALVE" SRSNAME="EPSG:26910">
    <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <Intersects>
        <PropertyName>Geometry</PropertyName>
        <Polygon srsName="EPSG:26910" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
          <exterior>
            <LinearRing>
              <posList> 489093.629 5456057.158 489092.66826402
                5456047.4034839 489089.822976626 5456038.02382838
                489085.202480615 5456029.37948835 489078.984339059
                5456021.80266094 489071.407511651 5456015.58451938
                489062.763171618 5456010.96402337 489053.383516101
                5456008.11873598 489043.629 5456007.158 489033.874483899
                5456008.11873598 489024.494828382 5456010.96402337
                489015.850488349 5456015.58451938 489008.273660941
                5456021.80266094 489002.055519385 5456029.37948835
                488997.435023374 5456038.02382838 488994.58973598 5456047.4034839
                488993.629 5456057.158 488994.58973598 5456066.9125161
                488997.435023374 5456076.29217162 489002.055519385
                5456084.93651165 489008.273660941 5456092.51333906
                489015.850488349 5456098.73148062 489024.494828382
                5456103.35197663 489033.874483899 5456106.19726402 489043.629
                5456107.158 489053.383516101 5456106.19726402 489062.763171618
                5456103.35197663 489071.407511651 5456098.73148062
                489078.984339059 5456092.51333906 489085.202480615
                5456084.93651165 489089.822976626 5456076.29217162
                489092.66826402 5456066.9125161 489093.629
                5456057.158
              </posList>
            </LinearRing>
          </exterior>
        </Polygon>
      </Intersects>
    </Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```